# Third Degree On Major

Tags: scales, modes

Compared to a major scale, what mode starts on scale degree three? I think it is minor but I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

The mode that starts on scale degree three of a major scale is the Phrygian mode.  It differs from the minor mode in that the second scale step is only a half tone above the tonic, rather than a whole tone.  In a way, it's more minor than minor.

Here's an example of music in the Phrygian mode:  *O Virtus Sapientiae*, by Hildegard of Bingen: